# Why am I getting Expression Expected?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, expression, structure

This is my simple CodeFile vb code for a username and password login form with a redirect to different 'members area' pages:

```
Public Class MyPage
Inherits Page
Private Structure Cred
    Public Username As String
    Public Password As String
    Public RedirectUrl As String
    Public Sub New(un As String, pw As String, Optional ru As String = "/admin/default.aspx")
        Username = un
        Password = pw
        RedirectUrl = ru
    End Sub
End Structure

Private ReadOnly _credentials As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Cred) =  New Cred(){New Cred("userone", "passwordone"), New Cred("usertwo", "passwordtwo"), New Cred("userthree", "passwordthree", "/admin/custom.aspx")}

Public Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim user = _credentials.SingleOrDefault(Function(x) x.Username = UserName.Text AndAlso x.Password = Password.Text)
    If user IsNot Nothing Then
        Session("Admin") = True
        Response.Redirect(user.RedirectUrl)
    Else
        Session("Admin") = False
        LtlLogin.Text = "<p>Sorry, you have provided incorrect login details.</p>"
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

It's on the line:

```
Dim user = _credentials.SingleOrDefault(Function(x) x.Username = UserName.Text AndAlso x.Password = Password.Text)
```

Thanks very much.

David.

Comment: obligatory warning about storing passwords as plaintext: dont

Comment: @Plutonix I am aware, thanks, but I'm just new to VB so taking it slow :)

Comment: Read about Classes and Structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `structure` against `class` for `Cred`.
Be aware that structures are value types and classes are reference types.

So:

```
Dim user = _credentials.SingleOrDefault(Function(x) x.Username = UserName.Text AndAlso x.Password = Password.Text)
```

always return a structure (when nothing found then the members of the structure gets their default values).

You cannot compare a structure to Nothing as ti is not a reference type.

Change structure to class and you will be fine.

Or change the check with:

```
If Not user.Equals(New Cred) Then
```

Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hkbth2a.aspx)

**UPDATE with examples**

Class Cred

```
Imports System.Linq

Module StartupModule

    Private ReadOnly _credentials As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Cred) = New Cred() {
        New Cred("userone", "passwordone"),
        New Cred("usertwo", "passwordtwo"),
        New Cred("userthree", "passwordthree", "/admin/custom.aspx")}

    Sub Main()
        Dim userName As String = ""
        Dim password As String = ""

        Dim crd = _credentials.Where(Function(x) x.Username = userName AndAlso x.Password = password).SingleOrDefault

        If crd Is Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine("user is nothing")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("user is something")
        End If


        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Class Cred
        Public Username As String
        Public Password As String
        Public RedirectUrl As String
        Public Sub New(un As String, pw As String, Optional ru As String = "/admin/default.aspx")
            Username = un
            Password = pw
            RedirectUrl = ru
        End Sub
    End Class


End Module
```

Structure Cred

```
Imports System.Linq

Module StartupModule

    Private ReadOnly _credentials As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Cred) = New Cred() {
        New Cred("userone", "passwordone"),
        New Cred("usertwo", "passwordtwo"),
        New Cred("userthree", "passwordthree", "/admin/custom.aspx")}

    Sub Main()
        Dim userName As String = ""
        Dim password As String = ""

        Dim crd = _credentials.Where(Function(x) x.Username = userName AndAlso x.Password = password).SingleOrDefault

        If crd.Equals(New Cred) Then
            Console.WriteLine("user is nothing")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("user is something")
        End If


        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Structure Cred
        Public Username As String
        Public Password As String
        Public RedirectUrl As String
        Public Sub New(un As String, pw As String, Optional ru As String = "/admin/default.aspx")
            Username = un
            Password = pw
            RedirectUrl = ru
        End Sub
    End Structure


End Module
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, so if I change 'Structure' to 'Class' and add your new line of code after that line, it will work will it? Thanks for your help here.

Comment: I believe that if you change `Structure Cred` to `Class Cred` you are ready. I guess that `UserName.Text' is a text box or something.

Comment: Had to change `end class` from `end structure` as well, but I still get Expression Expected on that line. Any ideas what's wrong here. Yes Username.Text and Password.Text are asp:TextBox. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer with both class and structure. They both works fine. Take a look.

Comment: I also always use `Option Explicit:On` and  `Option Strict: On`

Comment: I'm trying to get the error you get but I can't. wtf?

Comment: Thanks so much for that. Very, very kind of you. However I'm using Dreamweaver. I'm using a CodeFile to store the above code. Using your code it's saying: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl)

Comment: My code is a quick test VB console application. Just for me to test the problem. When you get the error? At run time or while in editor (precompile error)?

Comment: Something is very suspicious. I can't figure it out.